# Buildroot external toolchain + parallel builds

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

Does buildroot external toolchain supports parallel builds ? Meaning I can have multiple builds done on my system referring to the same toolchain folder.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always use toolchain (gcc+uclibc) outside of buildroot, so it's possible to launch as many builds at the same time as you want: http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/buildroot.html#using_toolchain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, without any problem. When Buildroot uses an external toolchain, at the beginning of the build process, it creates a private copy of the toolchain sysroot into the Buildroot build directory. The build remains completely isolated from other builds.